# Are kotlin Type checks regarded as code smell when aggregating

Tags: kotlin, instanceof

In many cases instance checking is considered a code smell.

Is the following kotlin example considered a code smell?

```
interface Animal {
    val name: String
}

data class Lion(override val name: String) : Animal
data class Monkey(override val name: String) : Animal

fun areAllLions(animals: List<Animal>) = animals.all { it is Lion }
```

We can use a polymorphic call that will return the type but it might make the code harder to read/maintain.

Comment: I would not consider that a code smell, as long as you are not trying to type check a generic, I think that you should be in the clear. But then again, that is a personal opinion, and SO doesn't really like that.

Comment: I don't think the code you've shown is smelly; but I'd look carefully at why you need an `areAllLions()` method in the first place, as that might indicate smells elsewhere.  (Also, rather than a type-specific call, you could have a generic extension function such as `inline fun <reified T: Animal> List<Animal>.areAll() = all{ it is T }`, which you could call with `if (myList.areAll<Lion>()) …`.)

Comment: There are cases where polymorphism is more smelly than instance checks, and this is one of them. To solve this with polymorphism, you'd have to make the interface have an `isLion` property, and similar properties for every other Animal type you might need to check. That will balloon into unmaintainable code very fast as you add animal types. But like `@gidds` said, there could be a higher-up design issue that leads you to having to do a check like this in the first place. It depends on the reason why we need to know if everything in the collection is a Lion.